# Bookmarklet not autofilling

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a series of bookmarklets to autofill news sites quickly. The format I learned from Reddit and Hacker News' ([link)](https://news.ycombinator.com/bookmarklet.html) examples is this:

```
javascript:location.href='http://www.reddit.com/submit?url='
                                +encodeURIComponent(location.href)
                                +'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```

Where I encode each parameter based on the form field `name`. Following this pattern, I intend to fill these fields:

```
sub_name
email
author_name
title
link
body
```

I'll trigger the bookmarklet from any tech news site, like [this one](https://opensource.com/article/19/2/emoji-log-git-commit-messages), with the intention of submitting it to https://www.linuxtoday.com/contribute.html. My test case of trying a couple fields isn't working:

```
javascript:location.href='https://www.linuxtoday.com/contribute.html?link='
                                +encodeURIComponent(document.href)
                                +'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```

This is as advanced as I've gotten in JavaScript. What's a straightforward way to get these parameters and submit them?